# Spring Data JPA & runtime native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I know it is possible to execute a native query by defining it in the repository class with @Query annotation and nativeQuery = true flag.

What I need is to execute a native query that comes from e.g. file. The point is that it is dynamic and it cannot be defined in advance.

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Use the `EntityManager` directly.